# How to bring an activity to front in android?

Tags: android

I am using moveTasktoBack() function to send my activity to background.
I want to bring my activity to front when a timer in my activity finishes. I am using the phone back key to send the activity to back. How do I do that? Help please.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232238/how-to-bring-an-activity-to-foreground-top-of-stack

Comment: @EricSchlenz actually that link discusses how to rearrange activities within a task. This doesn't solve OP's problem. He wants to know how to bring a task from the background to the foreground.

Comment: To bring a task to the front, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29769255/769265

Comment: why so many answer to confuse! when each intent flag has different meaning and purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Exact Same issue that is mentioned on this Question.

Sloved it with following code snippet.   `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)`; actauul which brings back the activity to front.

```
Intent i=new Intent(ApplicationStatus.this,NotifyActivity.class);
                    //i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                    i.putExtra("ID_TimeLeft",String.valueOf(TimeLeft));
                    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) with the appropriate flags. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to create a new task to contain your activity if one doesn't already exist. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to bring your activity to the front of the task if it's not already there.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

context.startActivity(intent);
```