# Reusing the main activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a main activity from where I will be switching from one activity to 
another..So i don't want to re initialize every time..After the first time 
of creation , the same activity should be called without having to create it
over and over again..how do I do this? #newbie-android

Comment: don't finish main activity when you calling next activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is simply start both your activities and switch between them by bringing them to the foreground. You should refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2232238/394933) for a possible solution. This [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) might also help.