# Is there a way to get back to the app when a outgoing phone call is executed?

Tags: android, phone-call

I have an App where a "Help Call" can be invoked. And I want that the call is running in background. So is there a way to get back to my app and hide the android phone call GUI ?

Comment: No. A phone is, after all, a phone. You shouldn't need to disrupt an outgoing phone call and, most importantly, you shouldn't be able to make a 'hidden' phone call (which is basically what you're describing).

Comment: Please have a look to this [answer][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232238/how-to-bring-an-activity-to-foreground-top-of-stack

Comment: Is there a way to trigger the back button or the home button programmatically while I'm in the phone call GUI? Because when I press the back or home button I get back to my app. But the user shouldn't press it by itself it should go automatically?