# Bring Fragment to top of stack

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, back-stack

When adding activities to the stack, I can do something like this suggests:
[How to bring an activity to foreground (top of stack)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232238/how-to-bring-an-activity-to-foreground-top-of-stack)

However, I have a Navigation Drawer that uses fragments. I add these fragments to my back stack via the below code:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, new EntryFragment());
                transaction.addToBackStack(activity.mTitle.toString());
                transaction.commit();
```

The problem is, I now need to take a fragment that is already part of the back stack and bring it to the top, dropping all fragments currently above it out of the stack. Essentially what `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flags would do when using activities.

How do I accomplish this with fragments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following method to return to the instance of the `Fragment` on the backstack:

```
activity.getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(tag, 0);
```

Note, that in your `FragmentTransaction` you will need to define a unique tag for each `Fragment` you commit to the backstack and retrieve that tag to return to the fragment here.