# How To Bring a working activity to ForeGround

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-broadcastreceiver, background-foreground

I am sending a broadcast when notification received and clicked on it to open a certain fragment. But when my application is on background this is not working. Is there any way to bring my activity to foreground without re-open it again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bring an activity to foreground (top of stack)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232238/how-to-bring-an-activity-to-foreground-top-of-stack)

Comment: What do you mean by "application is on background" and "bring my activity to foreground"? What behavior should the user see? What did you try? And what is not working about it?