# Triggering an Application launch from bluetooth device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth device that I can connect to an android phone, and I need to launch a specific application when a certain button is pressed on the Bluetooth Device.

So on press A--> Application A needs to be opened.

As of now, I am attempting to build an android application which can scan for and connect to the bluetooth device, with a set of built-in keymaps (A->Application A, etc), and the application would open up the application corresponding to the keymap, but this approach has its limitations in that I was not able to successively select buttons to transfer between apps.

Would there be a way to directly interact with the android kernal from BlueTooth to try to directly open up desired applications?

Comment: `but this approach has its limitations` - what limitations?

Comment: I was not able to transfer between applications with successive button clicks on the device. I may be wrong, however.

Comment: You'll have to setup the bluetooth monitor as a background service on phone, from there its just which app launch intent to fire.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a number of ways to get what you want, depending on your circumstances.  We can provide more help for specifics if you post some of the code you're currently using to start the apps. It never hurts to [review the basics](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html) of using Intents to start Activities.

Just guessing, but you may need to [bring the requested activity to the foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232238/how-to-bring-an-activity-to-foreground-top-of-stack) if it has already started and something else has focus.