# Bringing activity to front with an app in foreground

Tags: android, android-intent

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232238/how-to-bring-an-activity-to-foreground-top-of-stack), I've been trying to bring an activity to the front as soon as the user tries to leave it (I'm currently using the intent inside `onUserLeaveHint`). But `[FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT][2]` only works if after leaving my app, the user doesn't open another app. 
The process is somewhat as follows:

```
User -> Activity A -> User presses home button -> Home screen opens -> Activity A comes to front

User -> Activity A -> User presses home button -> Home screen opens -> User opens Activity B -> Activity A doesn't come to front
```

[Alarmy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=droom.sleepIfUCan) has counteracted this, and I'd like to follow a similar solution.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!