# Prevent recreating alive activity when launching from notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

From Android Oreo 8.0 (26 API) when using code for launching activity, it won't create a new activity if previous instance wasn't destroyed and still alive, but on previous Android (e.g. Marshmallow, Nougat) it always creates a new activity in any case.

Why does it behave so differently depending on Android version?

I want to prevent creating a new instance of activity and just bring to front existing (if it's still alive) starting from Android 23 (Marshmallow) when clicking on notification. For now it only works starting from Oreo Android (26)

```
val intent = Intent(this, TestActivity::class.java).apply {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
}

val pendingIntentt = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
)

val ... = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
    ...
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Android 8. With this set of `Intent` flags it should ALWAYS destroy all existing activities and create a new instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to bring an existing instance of the app to the foreground, or create a new instance if the app isn't running (foreground or background), then just use a launch `Intent` in your `Notification`:

```
val intent = getPackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("my.package.name")
```

Comment: Yes or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/3227127/7767664

Comment: Thanks. This works well. Kotlin -> `context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.packageName)`

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag

Comment: it doesn't matter what flags you set for intent, on Android <= Nougat it always recreates activity